# VBA Dynamically insert bell graph

Tags: excel, vba, normal-distribution

I'm trying to use VBA to insert a bell graph on the active worksheet. The idea is that different data will be pasted into these worksheets and the end users will click a button to generate the graph.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub insert_bell()
    
    ' Insert Scatter
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmooth, 1300).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Office_Active!$L$41:$M$198")
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Office_Active").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("L41:L198"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
    ' Sort Data
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Office_Active").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Column L has my x values and M has my y values.
I think the main things I need to do is to make `Source:=Range("Office_Active!$L$41:$M$198")` dynamic as it will not always be this sheet name or range and make this `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Office_Active").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _ Key:=Range("L41:L198")` this dynamic as again it will not always be this range.

Is this the most efficient way to achieve this and how would I go about making the two points above dynamic?

Comment: Just have a template with the chart built ready and paste in the data.

Comment: Will the top-left corner of the data always be in the same cell (eg L41)?

Comment: @DS_London Yes it will

Comment: Then perhaps set up a 'dynamic range' in the sheet. In short, you create a Name in the Name Manager whose range is defined by a formula (usually containing the OFFSET function). There are plenty of examples around for doing this. You can then specify this name for the chart data.

Comment: Thanks @DS_London - would this be more efficient than using VBA? Do you know how I can refer to the active sheet rather than the sheet named `Office_Active`?

Comment: The idea is that the chart is always there on the sheet, and uses the dynamic range which adjusts according to the size of the pasted data. In that scenario you don't need VBA, just rely on spreadsheet formulae.